# <a href> does not make phone numbers clickable in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone, ipad

I want that the phone number in my web page should be click able. I have application which has two web pages both containing numbers. In both of them I have used `<a>` tag for numbers to make them call able. It works fine in one of my web page, but is not working in the other page. I am not able to find the root cause for it.

I am considering that use of different elements on the two web pages must be causing this issue. Please any kind of help is most welcome.

I have tried every solution that has been listed here for such a question. But I'm not able to still find the root cause or find a solution for my problem.

Comment: Show us your HTML.  Also, what platform?

Comment: Are you marking them up right? Show the code.

Comment: I am doing this for iPhone and iPad. Its a mobile browser application. I am dynamically adding content to my web page using javascript.

Comment: Google search immediately found this http://allwebco-templates.com/support/S_smartphone-link.htm  Basically, use `tel:` in the `href` attribute.

Comment: Yes I am marking t hem write as similar code is working on the 2nd web page in my mobile application

Comment: We need to see the first page then as there's something wrong with it.

Comment: I used the below code in the body of my web page, but it is not displaying the hyper link                                                                 <a href='tel:1212313'>Click to call</a>

Comment: Can you give us a link?

Comment: Yes the anchor is in the DOM. I can also see the anchor text "Click to call", but nothing happens when I click on it. If I open the page in browser then it shows me the hyper link

Comment: Well, I figured out the problem and also the solution for it. I had a parent <div> tag which consisted of other tags and also <a> tag. So it was not recognizing the click event. So I had to distinguish between the tags when click event was fired. I used the following      var targer = event.srcElement;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a href="tel:+1-800-275-2273">Call</a>
```

Comment: <a href="tel:+1-800-275-2273">Call</a>                                        Works great in browser, but not in the mobile browser

Comment: try this
<a href="tel://1-555-555-5555">+1 (555) 555-5555</a>

Comment: you can also try <a href='callto:1300111222'>Click to call</a>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either “tel:” or “tel://”

for example:

```
<!-- Embedded within normal page text -->
<p>If you'd like to talk, <a href="tel:5555555">Call Me!</a></p>
<!-- Linking a custom image -->
<a href="tel://555-5555"><img src="phone.png" alt="Call Now!" /></a>
<!-- Cross-platform compatible (Android + iPhone) -->
<a href="tel://1-555-555-5555">+1 (555) 555-5555</a>
```

Refer this for more info:
**http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/phone-number-links/**

Hope this helps!